# Cannot create date object which works in IE

Tags: javascript, date

Well I have this code:

```
maxdate = saved['maxdate'];
var maxdate = new Date(maxdate.split('.').reverse().join(','));
maxdate.setDate(maxdate.getDate() + 60); //add 60 days

console.log(saved['maxdate']);
console.log(maxdate);
console.log(formatDate(maxdate));
```

and formatDate function:

```
function formatDate(date) {
    var monthNames = [
        "01", "02", "03",
        "04", "05", "06", "07",
        "08", "09", "10",
        "11", "12"
    ];

    var day = date.getDate();
    var monthIndex = date.getMonth();
    var year = date.getFullYear();

    return day + '.' + monthNames[monthIndex] + '.' + year;
}
```

In chrome result from the console.logs is:

```
13.05.2019
Fri Jul 12 2019 00:00:00 GMT+0300 (Eastern European Summer Time)
12.07.2019
```

Everything is OK, but in IE it returns me:

```
13.05.2019
[date] Invalid Date[date] Invalid Date
NaN.undefined.NaN
```

So .. probably `new Date()` doesn't work correctly in IE, any ideas ?

Comment: Yes, use [moment.js](https://momentjs.com/) and save yourself a headache

Comment: Just use a valid ISO 8601 date format (`"2019,05,13"` isn't one)

Comment: @Andreas You are right, it works with `new Date(mindate.split('.').reverse().join('-'));` instead of comma. Will you post an answer or delete the question ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Parsing date strings with the Date constructor is strongly discouraged](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date#Parameters) due to implementation differences across browsers (which is exactly what you experienced). If you can count on a specific format like the example in your question, it is relatively easy to parse the date string yourself and then pass the date parts to the constructor. For example (there are more elegant ways to do this, but tried to avoid any ES6 syntax below since you are using this in IE):

```js
function parseDate(d) {
  var parts = d.split('.');
  return new Date(parts[2], parts[1] - 1, parts[0]);
}

function formatDate(d) {
  var m = d.getMonth() + 1;
  m = m < 10 ? '0' + m : m;
  return d.getDate() + '.' + m + '.' + d.getFullYear();
}

var maxdate = parseDate('13.05.2019');
maxdate.setDate(maxdate.getDate() + 60);
console.log(formatDate(maxdate));
// 12.07.2019
```

Comment: The *parseDate* function tries too hard, there is no need for reverse/map/parseInt, it can be `var parts = d.split('.');
  return new Date(parts[2], parts[1] - 1, parts[0]);`. ;-)

Comment: @RobG - splitting time between python and js sometimes results in things like this that can be simplified quite a bit due to implicit type coercion in js. The use of `reverse` was just sloppy piggybacking off of OP's original code. Appreciate the feedback so that this can be cleaned up (see edit).